# Best practice for a global script in Symfony controllers

Tags: php, symfony

I have a lot of bundles in my application and I need to include a script at the beginning of each of these controllers that checks for a certain variables existence. In efforts to have a DRY application, what is the best practice to include a global script at the beginning of these controllers. The script I have will redirect the user to a specific controller is the check fails. Thanks.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: [How to Setup before and after Filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)